# 500 error after configuration page, setting up magento with substore

Tags: .htaccess, magento, installation

I have created a working magento site now I am trying to create a test environment based on the existing working site.  It is on the same server and will be under a different sub domain.

workingSubDomain.domain.com/store/
newSubDomain.domain.com/store/

I have kept the substore directory structure the same as the working site.

I have gone through and set all of the folders to 755 with the app/etc/, media, var set to 777

After I click continue on the installation wizard configuration page I recieve a 500 error.

The server log file shows the following:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/magentoFolder/subStore/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Resource.php on line 133, referer: http://newSubDomain.domain.com/subStore/index.php/install/wizard/config/?config%5Blocale%5D=en_US&config%5Btimezone%5D=America%2FChicago&config%5Bcurrency%5D=USD
```

I have tried the following url rewrites in the .htaccess folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /clint/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /clint/index.php [L]
```

and

```
RewriteBase /magentoFolder/subStore
```

and

```
RewriteBase /magentoFolder/subStore/
```

and

```
RewriteBase /magentoFolder/
```

and

```
RewriteBase /subStore/
```

I have cleared out the var folder as well.

Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

Here is the code from line 133 in the resource.php file:

```
 * Set module version into DB
 *
 * @param string $resName
 * @param string $version
 * @return int
 */
public function setDbVersion($resName, $version)
{
    $dbModuleInfo = array(
        'code'    => $resName,
        'version' => $version,
    );

    if ($this->getDbVersion($resName)) {
        self::$_versions[$resName] = $version;
        return $this->_getWriteAdapter()->update($this->getMainTable(),
                $dbModuleInfo,
                array('code = ?' => $resName));
    } else {
        self::$_versions[$resName] = $version;
        return $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insert($this->getMainTable(), $dbModuleInfo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not an apache error, it's a php error. Take a look at `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/magentoFolder/subStore/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Resource.php`, line **133**

Maybe it's a database connection error.

Comment: I went on and did some more looking.  I am going through the Magento install process, which is supposed to build out the local.xml file.  This file will have the connection settings.  I am just using localhost for the Host value